# How to write this code from haml into ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

This code is written in `haml` template, how can I rewrite it to `erb`:

```
- @recipe.each_slice(3) do |recipes|
    .row
        - recipes.each do |recipe|
            .col-md-4
                .recipe
                    .image_wrapper
                        = link_to recipe do
                            = image_tag recipe.image.url(:medium)
                    %h2= link_to recipe.title, recipe
```

Comment: Try with this tool https://www.haml-converter.com/

Answer (score 0):

It may looks like this:

```
<% @recipe.each_slice(3) do |recipes| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% recipes.each do |recipe| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="recipe">
          <div class="image_wrapper">
            <%= link_to recipe do %>
              <%= image_tag recipe.image.url(:medium) %>
            <% end %>
            <h2><%= link_to recipe.title, recipe %></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```